# asp.net updatepanel inside usercontrol reload the whole control

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I want to create a user control that represents a progress bar.

**ASCX:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ProgressBar.ascx.cs" Inherits="A2Controls.Controls.ProgressBar" %>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<%# this.Value %>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <%# this.Value %>%">
        <span class="sr-only"><%# this.Value %> Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
public partial class ProgressBar : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="clock" OnTick="clock_Tick" Interval="1000" Enabled="true"></asp:Timer>
        <uc1:ProgressBar runat="server" ID="ProgressBar" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers  >
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="clock" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void clock_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ProgressBar.Value++;
}
```

The problem is that every time the tick function is called, the updatepanel refreh and reload the whole usercontrol (calling the constructor I mean)! I've tried to put the updatepanel logic inside the usercontrol but there is no difference.

How can I prevent the usercontrol re-instantiate again?

Comment: Do you mean that every time the `Value` property is reset to 0?

Comment: not only this , but if I declare the constructor and I put a breakpoint, I can see that is hit every time I update the updatepanel. So if I do something like this

prgBar.Value = 50;
uPanel.Update();

(or wait for the timer to "tick")

A new ProgressBar is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your `Value` property to this:

```
public int Value
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["Value"] != null)
            return (int)ViewState["Value"];
        else
            return 0;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["Value"] = value;
    }
}
```

In this way you keep the property's value across postbacks.

`HTTP` is a stateless protocol. Unfortunately you have to use some kind of trick to persist data across requests like the `ViewState` does. You better have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to deeply understand that there's nothing wrong here.

Comment: Ok, this does the trick, but what I don't understand is why.
I mean, if I modify the control from internal I expect that the same instante survive and only the method "Render" will be call. There is a lot of things that I've tried to made but it's really difficult if everytime the control is completely rebuilt!

Comment: `HTTP` is a stateless protocol. Unfortunately you have to use some kind of trick to persist data across requests like the `ViewState` does. You better have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to deeply understand that there's nothing wrong here.